# How to obtain an origin-destiny Matrix from a Json in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, matrix

Having a JSON file like:

```
[ {"fecha" : "2013-07-01","indicativo" : "3195","nombre" : "MADRID,RETIRO","orig" : "10","dest" : "122","value" : "15"},{"fecha" :"2013-07-02","indicativo" : "3195","nombre" : "MADRID, RETIRO","orig" :"15","dest" : "5","value" : "15"},{"fecha" : "2013-07-03","indicativo" :"3195","nombre" : "MADRID, RETIRO","orig" : "5","dest" : "15","value" :"15"},{"fecha" : "2013-07-04","indicativo" : "3195","nombre" : "MADRID,RETIRO","orig" : "10","dest" : "122","value" : "15"}]
```

What I'm trying to obtain is a matrix that has orig field value as row y dest field value as a column. In the matrix, I would like to have the number of occurrences that have this orig and dest.

Example with the provided data:

```
| data | 5 | 10 | 15 | 122 |
|------|---|----|----|-----|
| 5    | 0 | 0  | 1  | 0   |
| 10   | 0 | 0  | 0  | 2   |
| 15   | 1 | 0  | 0  | 0   |
| 122  | 0 | 0  | 0  | 0   |
```

Basically I want to ghave a table taht shows me for exampe that for orig =10 and dest =122 I hav in the json 2 ocurrencies.

I understand I need to paser first json and transform it into a dataframe.

The problem is once I have this df, how I can create a matrix with as many rows as different orig and dest I have ( notice that they re lije bases ID and if Ihave a number 122 in dest but not in orig this means that no one trvae form this point but some of them arrrived to it).

Thinking I could imagine that I need first to extract different id I have in orig and dest , and then parsing each rown of the json and incrementin by one the df[orig][dest] position. But Is there any other more effiencient and quickly solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have loaded your JSON file into a `list` of `dict` named `data`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(['orig', 'dest']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This makes groups of all the unique `orig, dest` pairs and gets the size of each group (in other words, how many rows have those two unique values of `orig` and `dest`), which will form one value in the final dataframe.

With `unstack`, we can convert one level of the index to column names such that the unique values of `orig` are in the index and those for `dest` are in the columns.

Finally, we fill the null values (representing pairs which did not exist) with 0 and cast the dataframe back to `int` for presentability.

Testing with randomly generated data:

```
orig_data = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 100, p=[0.35, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05])
dest_data = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 100, p=[0.20, 0.25, 0.25, 0.20, 0.10])

data = [{'orig': orig, 'dest': dest} for orig, dest in zip(orig_data, dest_data)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(['orig', 'dest']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
dest   a  b  c  d  e
orig                
a      4  9  8  4  3
b     11  8  5  4  6
c      5  2  3  4  5
d      4  3  3  1  3
e      1  0  3  1  0
```